# Как остановить на время программу?

Tags: c++

как на время остановить программу на c++?

Comment: sleep или ctrl+s пробовали?

Comment: Что значит "на время"? "На заранее заданный промежуток времени" или просто "приостановить временно с клавиатуры"?

Comment: Напомнило старый анекдот: "Товарищ прапорщик, остановите поезд!" "Поезд стой, ать-два!" "Товарищ прапорщик, остановите программу на C++!" "Программа стой, ать-два!"

Comment: В консоле?!?! Если так, то все просто: system("pause");

Answer (score 1):

Если нужно совсем по стандарту C++11 :) - то, например, что-то вроде

```
this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::milliseconds(500));
```

Comment: Перед этим подключить `chrono` и `thread`

Comment: А еще вызвать сразу во всех потоках.

Comment: VTT не обязательно, тут уже по надобности

Comment: @Duoxx Ну если какой-то поток продолжает работу, то программа в целом также продолжает работу.